# Why it is important to understand when a particular problem is algorithmically “unsolvable.” How should I deal with this type of problems?

Tags: algorithms

So I learned that there are some problems that cannot be solved in computer science but I want to know why is it important to understand the unsolvable algorithm and how should I deal with it.

Comment: Welcome to CS.SE!  That's pretty broad.  What research and reading have you already done?  What do you already understand?  Can you help narrow down the question at all?

Comment: Instead of "unsolvable", we usually talk about "undecidable" or "intractable".

Comment: If a problem is undecidable, then you know that no algorithm decides it, and so it is pointless to look for one.